# Getting Android 4.x on the HTC Holiday (with complications)

Tags: rom-flashing, clockworkmod-recovery, 2.3.3-gingerbread, pac-rom, s-off

**Device:** AT&T HTC Holiday w/ Android 2.3 & no service

**Goal:** To get Android 4.x (any derivative) working on said device.

**Problem:** When I tried to install the PACMAN ROM (by loosely following the instructions provided at [Update HTC Raider/Velocity/Vivid/Holiday TO Android 4.4.4 KITKAT](http://www.crazyadvisors.com/update-htc-raider-velocity-vivid-holiday-to-4-4-4-kitkat/)) I got my phone stuck in a boot loop, meaning I can't S-OFF it using the tools provided at unlimited.io. (ControlBear is too impatient waiting for the phone to reboot because the phone is perpetually in a slow-to-start first-run state as it can't get past PACMAN's language selection screen before restarting itself, I'm assuming because the phone knows PACMAN isn't signed by HTC so it kills it) It doesn't help that ControlBear is closed source, meaning I can't modify it to suit my specific conditions.

**The bright side:** I have the recovery "CWM-based Recovery (by @KDH4865) v5.0.2.7" installed on the phone, so I can flash any OS ROM I want, it's just not guaranteed to work.

**Problem (cont'd):** I don't have a backup of anything.

**The bright side (cont'd):** I imagine installing a ROM that is signed by HTC might work, such as that over-the-air update to ICS which was never received. Alternatively, I have heard chatter on the PACMAN forums about "flashing boot.img" as an alternative to S-OFF, and I have no idea what that means. All I know of are the OS partition, the user data partition, the bootloader (on a separate BIOS chip?), the recovery partition, and the GSM antenna which does that nasty S-ON security stuff. I am clearly missing a small chunk of information in my brain.

Where might one go from my current situation in pursuit of one's goal?

EDIT: It turns out HTC gives away what it calls "ROMs" in Windows executable format for its devices free of charge. Apparently it's some kind of "RUU" thing, which I guess is like Android open heart surgery. I'll try that and see how it works.